# Does MOXy need anything special when using with schema-derived classes?

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I saw this question:

[Using Moxy as JAXB Implementation and setting jaxb.properties with more than one POJO package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403145/using-moxy-as-jaxb-implementation-and-setting-jaxb-properties-with-more-than-one)

And wanted to ask the following:

Does MOXy need anything special when using with schema-derived classes? For instance, are `jaxb.properties` files required in each of the packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following applies to whether the classes were generated from an XML Schema, or were hand built POJOs.

### Specifying MOXy as the JAXB Provider for an Individual `JAXBContext`

When creating a `JAXBContext` on a content path (one or more package names) using a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider (such as [**MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)) other than the default you need to include a `jaxb.properties` file with the appropriate entry in one of the packages.  For example given the code below the `jaxb.properties` file could be placed in either `com.example.pkg1` package or `org.example.pk2` package, or both.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.pkg1:org.example.pkg2");
```

The contents of the `jaxb.properties` must be:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

### Specifying MOXy as the Default JAXB Provider for all JAXBContexts

Alternatively you can configure your environment so that MOXy is the default JAXB provider so that the `jaxb.properties` file isn't necessary.  This is done as follows:

You could also leverage the `META-INF/services` mechanism to specify MOXy as the default JAXB provider:

1. Create a JAR that contains a file called `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` in the directory `META-INF/services`
2. The contents of the `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` file must be `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`
3. Add that jar to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I don't has right to comment, so i give a answer here.
Recently I choose MOXy in the project and meet the problem too. We use maven for build tool, if you use maven too, you can simply create diretory `META-INF/services` under the `resources` directory, and create a file named `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` under `META-INF/services`, then edit the file with contents `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`.