# JAXBException: "package" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

Tags: spring, hibernate, jaxb, moxy, dbunit

I have been playing with JAXB / MOXy a lot lately, **and it works great on all my tests and example codes**. I exclusively using binding files, that's why I'm using MOXy.

Please note that in all my examples, I'm NEVER using an ObjectFactory nor a jaxb.index, **and it works GREAT**.

When I get back to my business, I get a nasty JAXB Exception saying that my package does not contain an ObjectFactory or jaxb.index.

My project also invovles Spring and Hibernate, JUnit and DBUnit.

Here is some sample code: I have an abstract class called AContributionPhysicalSupport.

```
package org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TOV_CONTRIBUTION_PHYSICAL_SUPPORT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "SUPPORT_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 20)
public abstract class AContributionPhysicalSupport implements Serializable
{
/* *****************************************************************
 * 
 * PROPERTIES
 * 
 * *****************************************************************
 */

/**
 * for Serializable
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SUPPORT_ID")
private Long physicalSupportId;

@Column(name = "SUPPORT_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 20, updatable = false, insertable = false)
private String supportType;

/* *****************************************************************
 * 
 * CONSTRUCTORS
 * 
 * *****************************************************************
 */

public AContributionPhysicalSupport()
{

}

/* *****************************************************************
 * 
 * GETTERS AND SETTERS
 * 
 * *****************************************************************
 */

/**
 * @return the physicalSupportId
 */
public Long getPhysicalSupportId()
{
    return physicalSupportId;
}

/**
 * @param physicalSupportId
 *            the physicalSupportId to set
 */
public void setPhysicalSupportId(Long physicalSupportId)
{
    this.physicalSupportId = physicalSupportId;
}

/**
 * @return the supportType
 */
public String getSupportType()
{
    return supportType;
}

/**
 * @param supportType
 *            the supportType to set
 */
public void setSupportType(String supportType)
{
    this.supportType = supportType;
}

/* *****************************************************************
 * 
 * UTILS
 * 
 * *****************************************************************
 */

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.getClass() + " [physicalSupportId=" + physicalSupportId + ", supportType=" + supportType + "]";
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((physicalSupportId == null) ? 0 : physicalSupportId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((supportType == null) ? 0 : supportType.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof AContributionPhysicalSupport))
    {
        return false;
    }
    AContributionPhysicalSupport other = (AContributionPhysicalSupport) obj;
    if (physicalSupportId == null)
    {
        if (other.physicalSupportId != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (!physicalSupportId.equals(other.physicalSupportId))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (supportType == null)
    {
        if (other.supportType != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (!supportType.equals(other.supportType))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Class Video inherits from AContributionPhysicalSupport :

```
package org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TOV_VIDEO")
@DiscriminatorValue("VIDEO")
public class Video extends AContributionPhysicalSupport
{
/* *****************************************************************
 * 
 * PROPERTIES
 * 
 * *****************************************************************
 */

/**
 * for serializable
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "VIDEO_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 20)
private String videoType;

@Column(name = "VIDEO_SIZE")
private Long videoSize;

@Column(name = "VIDEO_LENGTH")
private Long videoLength;

/* *****************************************************************
 * 
 * CONSTRUCTORS
 * 
 * *****************************************************************
 */

public Video()
{
    super();
}

/* *****************************************************************
 * 
 * GETTERS AND SETTERS
 * 
 * *****************************************************************
 */

/**
 * @return the videoType
 */
public String getVideoType()
{
    return videoType;
}

/**
 * @param videoType
 *            the videoType to set
 */
public void setVideoType(String videoType)
{
    this.videoType = videoType;
}

/**
 * @return the videoSize
 */
public Long getVideoSize()
{
    return videoSize;
}

/**
 * @param videoSize
 *            the videoSize to set
 */
public void setVideoSize(Long videoSize)
{
    this.videoSize = videoSize;
}

/**
 * @return the videoLength
 */
public Long getVideoLength()
{
    return videoLength;
}

/**
 * @param videoLength
 *            the videoLength to set
 */
public void setVideoLength(Long videoLength)
{
    this.videoLength = videoLength;
}

/* *****************************************************************
 * 
 * UTILS
 * 
 * *****************************************************************
 */

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + " Video [videoType=" + videoType + ", videoSize=" + videoSize + ", videoLength="
            + videoLength + "]";
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = super.hashCode();
    result = prime * result + ((videoLength == null) ? 0 : videoLength.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((videoSize == null) ? 0 : videoSize.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((videoType == null) ? 0 : videoType.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (!super.equals(obj))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Video))
    {
        return false;
    }
    Video other = (Video) obj;
    if (videoLength == null)
    {
        if (other.videoLength != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (!videoLength.equals(other.videoLength))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (videoSize == null)
    {
        if (other.videoSize != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (!videoSize.equals(other.videoSize))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (videoType == null)
    {
        if (other.videoType != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (!videoType.equals(other.videoType))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is my binding file (there are other classes inheriting from AContributionPhysicalSupport....)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" package-name="org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation">

<java-types>

    <java-type name="AContributionPhysicalSupport">
        <xml-root-element name="contribution-physical-support" />
        <xml-type prop-order="physicalSupportId supportType" />
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-attribute java-attribute="physicalSupportId" name="support-id" />
            <xml-element java-attribute="supportType" name="support-type" />
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>

    <java-type name="ExternalFileFormat">
        <xml-root-element name="ext-file-format" />
        <xml-type prop-order="fileType fileSize" />
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-element java-attribute="fileType" name="file-type" />
            <xml-element java-attribute="fileSize" name="file-size" />
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>

    <java-type name="InternalFileFormat">
        <xml-root-element name="int-file-format" />
        <xml-type prop-order="fileSize" />
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-element java-attribute="fileSize" name="file-size" />
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>

    <java-type name="Video">
        <xml-root-element name="video" />
        <xml-type prop-order="videoType videoSize videoLength" />
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-element java-attribute="videoType" name="video-type" />
            <xml-element java-attribute="videoSize" name="video-size" />
            <xml-element java-attribute="videoLength" name="video-length" />
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>

</java-types>

</xml-bindings>
```

And now my test :

```
@Test
public void testYATMarshal() throws Exception
{
    Video toto = new Video();
    toto.setPhysicalSupportId(new Long(1));
    toto.setSupportType("VIDEO");
    toto.setVideoLength(new Long(358));
    toto.setVideoSize(new Long(5775));
    toto.setVideoType("avi");

    FileReader videoBindFile = new FileReader(
            "src/main/resources/xml-mapping/ContributionImpl-binding.xml");
    List<Object> videoBindList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    videoBindList.add(videoBindFile);

    Map<String, List<Object>> videoMetaMap = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
    videoMetaMap.put("org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation", videoBindList);
    Map<String, Object> videoProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    videoProperties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, videoMetaMap);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation",
            Video.class.getClassLoader(), videoProperties);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    marshaller.marshal(toto, System.out);
}
```

and last but not least the Exception :

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:347)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:431)
at org.pea.openVillages.dao.service.impl.ContributionDAOImplTest.testYATMarshal(ContributionDAOImplTest.java:187)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:216)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:172)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
... 33 more
```

More info :

- My test package (where I have my JUnit test class) contains a jaxb.properties file
- My JUnit test class is really a DBUnit / SpringJUnit class, since I want to marshal objects from a DB
- Marshalling from DB or marshalling a simple object (like shown in my example) generate the same Exception
- And, of course, adding a jaxb.index in the package doesn't change anything

Four eyes are better than two. I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong. If somebody sees it, please let me know.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated` - seems like you're not using MOXy but the built-in JAXB RI.

Please check the following post by Blaise:

> [Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as Your JAXB Provider](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)

See also the following question:

> [Does MOXy need anything special when using with schema-derived classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411849/does-moxy-need-anything-special-when-using-with-schema-derived-classes)

Comment: Thx for answering.

I have just figured out that it has something to do with the package where I'm marshalling my objects.

Let me explain:

I have 2 JUnit tests. The first one is in package

    org.pea.openVillages.dao.service.impl

and the other in

    org.pea.openVillages.pojo.contribution.implementation

(same package name as my classes, but in src/test/java)

Marshalling from the first test package **does not work**, whereas marshalling from the second **works!**

Why I need to know is: where do I put the    jaxb.properties file to be able to marshall from the first package?

Comment: Just to make myself clear: I do use MOXy, by placing a correct jaxb.properties somewhere. What I need to know is how do I marshal from somewhere else? can I do it ?

Comment: @avi613 Try the method with `META-INF/services` as Blaise described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411849/does-moxy-need-anything-special-when-using-with-schema-derived-classes

Comment: TOUCHDOWN Buddy! I have simply added the two packages like shown here    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.pkg1:org.example.pkg2");    and that did it!

Comment: @avi613 Glad it helped. :) Collective consciousness.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Lexicore in his comment did it for me!

I have setted the two packages as shown in [Blaise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26412494/303810):

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.pkg1:org.example.pkg2");
```

And that did it!

Thx man