# JAXB + OSGi with Java 11

Tags: java, jaxb, osgi, java-11, apache-felix

I'm trying to load the JAXB modules as OSGi bundles with Java 11 and Apache Felix using a POM-first approach (the OSGi meta data gets generated).

First I tried with:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

but this gives me the following runtime exception:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.  
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception: 
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
```

It might be related to the following issue, but I'm not sure: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-api/issues/78

So I tried with v3.0.0 but now one of my annotation processory which generate an XML document using JAXB, fails:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-module: Compilation failure
Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
```

I noticed that `jaxb-osgi-3.0.0.jar` does not provide the `com.sun.xml.bind` package anymore

I also tried to migrate from `javax.xml.bind` to `jakarta.xml.bind`, but the Maven Plugins, which generate POJO classes from XSDs, don't seem to be ready yet at the time of writing (neither `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin` nor `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin`).

My questions:

1. Where can I get the `com.sun.xml.bind` from?
2. How do the `jaxb-osgi` and `jaxb-impl` modules relate?
3. How is this all supposed to work?
4. How can I proceed?

**Update - background information**

I have the following setup based on the [Extender Pattern](https://enroute.osgi.org/FAQ/400-patterns.html#extender-pattern):

- core extender module M:

  - provides some JAXB classes
  - a BundleTracker to unmarshal XML documents from a META-INF sub-directory of some bundles X, Y, Z
  - an abstract custom annotation processor to marshal the XML documents
- extension modules A, B, C:

  - provide additional JAXB classes (generated from XSDs)
  - extensions are registered using Declarative Services
  - custom annotations
  - annotation processors to convert the annotation attributes to JAXB based models and generate the XML-document at the expected place
- extendee modules X, Y, Z

  - using the annotation of modules A, B, C
  - using the annotation processors of A, B, C to generate the XML-documents

Goal: it should be easy to create extendee modules such as X, Y, Z

Everything works fine with Java SE 8 where JAXB is still bundled with the JRE.

**Update 1**

Because the Maven plugins are not ready I'm stuck with v2.3.3 for now.

I changed the following:

- I'm providing a classloader when calling JAXBContext.newInstance
- I added the following configuration to the maven-bundle-plugin in several modules:

  com.sun.xml.bind.v2, *

This solved the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory` issues (it doesn't seem to be the correct solution for this, though), but now the ObjectFactory cannot be located though they were generated.

**Update 2**

I'm using now a modified `jaxb-osgi` bundle (see [issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1507)) and *Apache Aries SPI Fly Dynamic Weaving Bundle (1.3.2)* (the reference implementation of the OSGi ServiceLoader Mediator specification) and I added the following requirements to the core module M:

```
Require-Capability: [...],osgi.extender;filter:="(o
 sgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor)",osgi.serviceloader;filter:=
 "(osgi.serviceloader=javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory)";cardinality:=m
 ultiple,[...]"
```

The services seem to get detected:

```
2021-02-13 12:09:31 INFO org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log - Registered provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.JAXBContextFactory of service javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory in bundle com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi
2021-02-13 12:09:31 INFO org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log - Registered provider com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.code_injector.PluginImpl of service com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin in bundle com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi
2021-02-13 12:09:31 INFO org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log - Registered provider com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.locator.SourceLocationAddOn of service com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin in bundle com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi
2021-02-13 12:09:31 INFO org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log - Registered provider com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.sync.SynchronizedMethodAddOn of service com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin in bundle com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi
2021-02-13 12:09:31 INFO org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log - Registered provider com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.at_generated.PluginImpl of service com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin in bundle com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi
2021-02-13 12:09:31 INFO org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log - Registered provider com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.episode.PluginImpl of service com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin in bundle com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi
2021-02-13 12:09:31 INFO org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log - Registered provider com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.accessors.PluginImpl of service com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin in bundle com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi
```

But I still get:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found by
```

Why does it try to load the hard-coded default `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory` instead of `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.JAXBContextFactory` via ServiceLoader?

Comment: `com.sun.xml.bind` moved to `org.glassfish.jaxb.core` and `org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime` in the 3.0.0 release. The `jaxb-osgi` is a fat jar with all other JAXB jars and dependencies.

Comment: When using JAXB 3.0.0, did you check that you are using the `jakarta.xml` package instead of `javax.xml`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz: As I wrote, the Maven Plugins don't generate code with jakarta.xml packages yet. They still generate javax.xml based code. So this road seems to be blocked for now. Is there a way to get this working? Or is there another Maven Plugin I should use?

Comment: Download the `master` branch of `jaxb2-maven-plugin` on [github](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin) and install it to your local Maven repository. It generates JAXB 3.0.0 source code.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I've seen something on master, yes, but I don't know the state. I need something released to depend on. Also, I'm currently using the other Maven Plugin. Is there any other way? E.g. getting this running using the javax.xml package?

Comment: Looking further into you error messages: did you add the required `Import-Package` statements?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz which import statements do you mean exactly? I'm in the progress of upgrading a framework from Java 8 to Java 11. Everything works with Java 8.

Comment: I filed an issue here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1507

Answer (score 4):

Since each OSGI bundle uses its own classloader the JAXB API is not able to use the standard `ServiceLoader` to locate the JAXB implementation. However since version 2.2.2 the JAXB API can use [osgi-resource-locator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/osgi-resource-locator/2.5.0-b42) as a fallback.

Therefore, in order to use JAXB on Java 11, you just need to:

1. Add a dependency on the `javax.xml.bind` and `org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator` packages,
2. Deploy the [`osgi-resource-locator`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/osgi-resource-locator/2.5.0-b42) and [`jaxb-osgi`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-osgi/2.3.4) bundles together with your bundle.

**Remark**: if you want to use MOXy, you need additional steps, since MOXy does not ship with a `META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` file (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26407134/11748454)).